# Problemas con el API de GoogleMaps en laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax, google-maps, laravel-blade

En la aplicación laravel se muestro el listado (index.blade.php) de sucursales de una empresa y tengo un icono (opciones) para levantar una ventana modal (se encuentra incluída en el index.blade.php) en donde se debe mostrar la ubicación por google maps de esta oficina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@section('titulo')
    {{trans('message.sucursales.title')}}
@endsection

@section("scripts")
    <script src="{{asset("assets/pages/scripts/_crear.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset("assets/pages/scripts/_index.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset("assets/pages/scripts/admin/mapa/mapa.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Google Map -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=_API_CODE_&callback=initMap" async defer></script> 

@endsection

@section('contenido-cabecera')
@endsection

@section('contenido')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        @include('includes.menus.empresa_menu')
        @include('includes.dashboard.empresa_dashboard')
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">

        @include('includes.form-error')
        @include('includes.mensaje')

        @include('includes.cabeceras.empresa')
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="{{route('crear_sucursal_empresa')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-border-success"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> {{trans('message.sucursales.header_create')}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla-data">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>{{trans('message.table.name')}}</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{trans('message.table.type')}}</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{trans('message.table.city')}}</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{trans('message.table.address')}}</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{trans('message.table.contact')}}</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{trans('message.table.email')}}</th>
                                            <th>{{trans('message.table.state')}}</th>
                                            <th class="width70 sorting_asc_disabled sorting_desc_disabled"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($data['sucursales'] as $data)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$data->nombre}}</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{$data->tipo}}</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{$data->ciudad}}</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{$data->direccion}}</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{$data->contacto}}</td>
                                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a href="mailto:{{$data->correo}}" target="_blank" >{{$data->correo}}</a></td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                @if ( $data->estado == 1 )
                                                    <span class="label label-success">{{trans('message.object.active')}}</span>
                                                @else
                                                    <span class="label label-danger">{{trans('message.object.inactive')}}</span>
                                                @endif
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{$data->id}}" class="btn-accion-tabla tooltipsC editar_sucursal" title="{{trans('message.table.edit')}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                                @if( $data->tipo_id != 2869 )
                                                    <form action="{{route('eliminar_contrato', ['id' => $data->id])}}" class="d-inline form-eliminar" method="POST">
                                                        @csrf @method("delete")
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-accion-tabla eliminar tooltipsC" title="{{trans('message.table.delete')}}">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash text-danger"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                @endif
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{$data->id}}" class="btn-accion-tabla tooltipsC mostrar_mpapa" title="{{trans('message.object.map')}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </div>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('includes.modal.visualizar_mapa')
@endsection
```

El tema es lo siguiente, que al escoger el registro y pulsar en el icono de ubicación mantengo una función .js vía ajax que trae los datos de latitud y longitud de la base de datos

```
$('.mostrar_mpapa').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: url_global+"/admin/datos_mapa",
        data: { 
            id: id 
        },
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {    
            $('#id').val(data.id);
            $('#latitud').val(data.latitud);
            $('#longitud').val(data.longitud);
            $('#estado').val(data.estado);
            //
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                GoogleMap.initGoogleMap();
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
                    center: {
                        lat: data.latitud, 
                        lng: data.longitud
                    },
                    zoom: 18,
                });

                var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position  : {
                lat       : data.latitud, 
                lng       : data.longitud
                    },
                    map: map,
                    title: data.nombre
                });
            }
            $('#mapaModal').modal();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error de Mapa');
        }
    });
});
```

Todo funciona correctamente, pero el momento de mostrarse la modal no se muestra el mapa o mejor dicho el mapa sale en blanco y no entiendo por que no ejecuta la carga del api de google map.

```
<div id="mapaModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{trans('message.modal.mapping')}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">{{ trans('message.empresas.correo_2') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">{{ trans('message.empresas.correo_2') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="control-label">{{ trans('message.empresas.correo_2') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" name="direccion" id="direccion">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">{{trans('message.buttons.cancel')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe aclarar que en base a cada registro (puede tener muchas sucursales una empresa) se deberá cargar el mapa de la ubicación geográfica de esta.

Espero sus comentarios.

Comment: ¿aparece algún error en la consola?

Comment: ninguno... ejecuta completamente el código y no entiendo es por que no instancia la variable map para mostrar la ubicación geográfica.

Comment: ¿podrías editar la pregunta y agregar el código del modal? donde aparece `map_canvas`

Comment: ya se ecnuentra agragado la ventana modal para la referenca de la pregunta, pero el tema es que no ejecuta la funcion para la creacion o instancia de la variable map, es decir no ingresa en  function initMap() {
                GoogleMap.initGoogleMap();
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos posibles problemas aquí:

1. Defines una función que sirve de callback para Google Maps, pero la defines dentro del success de AJAX:

   ```
       function initMap() {
           GoogleMap.initGoogleMap();
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
               center: {
                   lat: data.latitud, 
                   lng: data.longitud
               },
               zoom: 18,
           });

           var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
           position  : {
           lat       : data.latitud, 
           lng       : data.longitud
               },
               map: map,
               title: data.nombre
           });
       }
   ```

   Lo ideal sería que la definas fuera de dicho contexto, o incluso, que la definas global. También podrías inicializar el mapa con determinadas características, y modificarlas cuando recibas la respuesta de la solicitud AJAX.
2. La otra posibilidad por la que pueda estar fallando, es algo ya conocido con Google Maps:

   > Normalmente no se puede inicializar un mapa en un elemento que esté oculto con `display: none;`

   En este caso, prueba mostrando primero el modal, y luego inicializando el mapa. Si esto no funciona, entonces deberás utilizar de otra forma los eventos de JavaScript o del framework que utilizas (jQuery).

Comment: gracias por los comentarios... procederé a las pruebas necesarias!!!